# := in VBA works like := in linux or = in C?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on vba and came across `:=`

What it does actually?
Sample example:

`msg:=Var1 & ": " & Chr(34)`


Basically my concern is whether it works like in linux, where you can use things like
`LIBPATH:= many library path`  or is it just like C language where it is simply used to assign a value to the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:=` is used when you assign value to `Arguments`.
It can be `Arguments` of `Object Method` or `Procedure`.

**Example1:**

```
myFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
```

In the code above, you use `:=` to assign value to `filefilter argument` in `GetOpenFilename` method.

**Example2:**

Suppose you have this `Procedure`.

```
Private Sub MyProcedure(MyValue as String)
'~~> code here
End Sub
```

Then you have your `Main Sub`

```
Sub Main()

mystring = "Hello"
'~~> assign value to MyProcedure argument
MyProcedure MyValue:=mystring

End Sub
```

Although, you really don't need to use `:=` in assigning `Procedure Argument`.
Below also works:

```
MyProcedure mystring
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just one more clarification. In linux, I think it helps to assign multiple values to a variable (for eg, you can assign many library paths to one variable LIBPATH using this `:=`). So, is it like that in vba also?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way in `VBA`. If you want to assign multiple values in a `Variable` you simply declare that `Variable` as `Variant` type then directly pass the multiple values using `=`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an  named argument.

A named argument consists of an argument name followed by a colon and an equal sign (:=), followed by the argument value. [See HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx)

Comment: plus one, the link you posted covers it all regarding procedure arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In some languages, `:=` is called an assignment statement. The contents on the right side of the `":="` are stored into the variable on the left side, e.g `sum:=5+2`

But in `vba` It is used for `"named arguments"`,